# scala - error: not found: value

Tags: scala, runtime-error, worksheet

I newly at scala and tried to pass some easy scala worksheet.

IDE is Intellij IDEA community edition and OS Ubuntu 12.04, `sbt` was installed correctly.

But it throws error - `error: not found: value`

OI can't understand why this happen:

***Code:***

```
object session {
  1 + 2
  def abs(x: Double) = if (x < 0) -x else x         <== update this line
  def sqrtIter(guess: Double, x: Double): Double =
    if (isGoodEnough(guess, x)) guess
    else sqrtIter(improve(guess, x), x)

  def isGoodEnough(guess: Double, x: Double) =
    abs(guess * guess - x) < 0.001

  def improve(guess: Double, x: Double) =
    (guess + x / guess) / 2
  def sqrt(x: Double) = sqrtIter(1.0, x)
  sqrt(2)
  sqrt(4)
}
```

***Output from right side of screen:***

```
> res0: Int = 3

> <console>:8: error: not found: value isGoodEnough
             if (isGoodEnough(guess, x)) guess else sqrtIter(improve(guess, x), x)  
                 ^
  <console>:8: error: not found: value improve
             if (isGoodEnough(guess, x)) guess else sqrtIter(improve(guess, x), x)  
                                                             ^
> <console>:8: error: not found: value abs
             abs(guess * guess - x) < 0.001
             ^
> improve: (guess: Double, x: Double)Double

> <console>:7: error: not found: value sqrtIter
         def sqrt(x: Double) = sqrtIter(1.0, x)
                               ^    
> <console>:8: error: not found: value sqrt
                sqrt(2)
                ^

> <console>:8: error: not found: value sqrt
                sqrt(4)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The complete error message is `error: not found: value abs`. The value "abs" wan't found. You want `math.abs`. Alternatively you could add `import math._` somewhere before you need these math functions.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. On the other side I prefer importing only what the program needs, for clarity, so I recommend to use "import math.abs".

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you. I didn't think importing math.abs or importing math._ were valid as abs was defined in the code.

What worked for me was reorganizing the order of the function definitions. You have to define something above before it can be used below.

```
object session {
  def abs(x: Double) = if (x<0) - x else x

  def isGoodEnough(guess: Double, x: Double) =
  abs(guess * guess - x) < 0.001

  def improve(guess: Double, x: Double) =
    (guess + x / guess) / 2
  def sqrtIter(guess: Double, x: Double): Double =
    if(isGoodEnough(guess, x)) guess
    else sqrtIter(improve(guess, x), x)


  def sqrt(x: Double) = { sqrtIter(1.0, x) }

  sqrt(2)
  sqrt(4)
}
```

Returned:

```
> abs: (x: Double)Double


> isGoodEnough: (guess: Double, x: Double)Boolean


> improve: (guess: Double, x: Double)Double


> sqrtIter: (guess: Double, x: Double)Double


> sqrt: (x: Double)Double



> res0: Double = 1.4142156862745097
> res1: Double = 2.0000000929222947
```

Answer (score 1):

And some easiest way without redundant code:

```
object session {
  1 + 2
  def abs(x: Double) = if (x < 0) -x else x
  def sqrt(x: Double) = {

  def sqrtIter(guess: Double): Double =
    if (isGoodEnough(guess)) guess
    else sqrtIter(improve(guess))

  def isGoodEnough(guess: Double) =
    abs(guess * guess - x) / x < 0.001

  def improve(guess: Double) =
    (guess + x / guess) / 2
  sqrtIter(1.0)
  }
  sqrt(2)
  sqrt(4)
  sqrt(1e-16)
  sqrt(1e60)
}
```